How to calibrate a 3 phase IPM motor position?
I am currently working on developing motor controller for 3 phase IPM motor. I am able to run IPM on field oriented control algorithm. However I am unable to calculate exact offset angle for motor position calibration. Motor has a inbuilt ABZ sensor for providing position feedback.


To help get an answer can you [edit] the question to include links to the documentation for the motor and controller which are being used.

Hello and welcome.  Can I ask what "IPM" and "ABZ" mean?

IPM refers to interior permanent magnet motor. ABZ refer to postion sensor, where  AB refers to the quadrature pulses and Z pulse gives the index signal.
